# Imperatively request interpolated value from a React Native animation

Tags: animation, react-native, colors, interpolation

I'm trying to retrieve the current color from a react-native animation. It's mapped through `interpolate` to a set of color strings.

```
class IconTransition extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  protected _param: number = 0;

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      param: new Animated.Value(0)
    };

    this.state.param.addListener(param => {
      this._param = param.value;
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.spring(this.state.param, {
      mass: 1,
      stiffness: 10,
      damping: 10,
      toValue: 1
    });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    // I want to do something like this. Would be awesome
    // if I could avoid the listener in the constructor.
    //
    // const currentColor = Animated.interpolate.get({
    //   currentInput: this._param,
    //   outputRange: ["#FFFFFF", "#000000"]
    // });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AnimatedIcon
        {...this.props}
        color={this.state.param.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: ["#FFFFFF", "#000000"]
        })}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve the color, as interpolated, *should the animation not finish*. I'm aware I could probably use an external library such a [chroma-js](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/) (in particular, the [`chroma.mix`](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/#chroma-mix) function) to achieve this - but there are different ways to interpolate through two different colors and I'd rather not depend on an external library if I can avoid it.

So... the greater question remains, how can I imperatively request an output value from the `interpolation` API? Can we not `listen` on interpolated values, just as we do with `Animated.Value()`?

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to do the same for a while now and there's a few things you need to keep in mind:

- Since you're trying to update a prop that is not a style prop your
  best bet is to use the `addListener` and `setNativeProps` methods
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations#setnativeprops
- The interpolation has a `__getValue` method to check the current value.
  This is the function you want to call in the listener to check the
  current interpolated value
  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Animated/src/nodes/AnimatedInterpolation.js#L327
- Colors cannot be passed to props like that when set from setNative
  props, it has to be passed through `processColor`
  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/StyleSheet/processColor.js

If you put that all together you can get somthing like the following, which worked in my case:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, processColor} from 'react-native';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

class BackgroundColorLinearGradientText extends React.Component {

    /**
     * Class constructor.
     */
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.backgroundColor = new Animated.Value(0);
        this.backgroundColor.addListener(i => {
            let interpolated = this.backgroundColor.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 1],
                outputRange: ['#FF0000', '#00FF00'],
            }).__getValue();
            if (this.background) {
                this.background.setNativeProps({colors: [processColor(interpolated), processColor(this.background.props.colors[1])]})
            }
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Animated.timing(this.backgroundColor, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 3000,
        }).start();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <LinearGradient ref={i => this.background = i} colors={['red', 'blue']} style={{flex: 1}}>
                <View style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                }}>
                    Content
                </View>
            </LinearGradient>
        );
    }
}
```

This will create a screen which has a red to blue gradient background, transitioning to green to blue in three seconds.

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work in typescript? `.__getValue()` is not found as a function on that object.

Comment: @NilsBacke declare a custom type for the target of the `__getValue()` call: `type Interpolated = Animated.AnimatedInterpolation & { __getValue?: () => any }`